# select multi numbers of words after @ sign from using php

Tags: php, string

yesterday i asked a question that how to select specific word from string which is having @ sign with it.
someone told me this solution

```
$abc = "hello @john what are you doing";
$found = preg_match('/@([^-\s]*)/', $abc, $matches);

    $name = null;
    if ($found) {
      $name = $matches[1];
    }
```

it works like a charm but the problem is it only select first word with @ sign if the string have alot of words like that. so now i need a loop which selects all the words in string which are having @ sign with them.

Comment: You have a starter for 10. What have you tried for yourself?

Comment: Use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get all matches of your regular expression, not just the first one.

```
$abc = "hello @john what on earth are @stella and @steve doing";
$found = preg_match_all('/@([^-\s]*)/', $abc, $matches);

if ($found) {
    foreach ($matches[1] as $name) {
        echo "Name: $name", PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: john
Name: stella
Name: steve
```